# Error accessing array properties json

Tags: php, json, wikipedia-api

I am trying to access various properties from Wikipedia's Infobox through using the API. I am using the following script for a search term Google for example and would like to return the industry however am getting the messages Undefined property... and Notice: Trying to get property of non-object. I'm sure I'm missing something really simple please assist. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<h2>Search</h2>
<form method="post">
Search: <input type="text" name="q" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['q'])) {
$search = $_POST['q'];

$url_2 = "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?                                                                  
action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&titles=$search&rvsection=0";
$res_2 = file_get_contents($url_2);
$data_2 = json_decode($res_2);

?>

<h2>Search results for '<?php echo $search; ?>'</h2>
<ol>
<?php echo $data_2->pages->revisions->industry; ?>

<?php 
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should start with a `var_dump()` of the relevant variables (the url, the result, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

see
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php
for looping through the revision array you are describing.

When I look at the link you are using to access,  the JSON data returns the message

```
Formatting of continuation data will be changing soon. To continue using the
'rawcontinue' parameter. To begin using the new format, pass an empty string
for 'continue' in the initial query.
```

the JSON data has no "revisions" object under the "pages" object, I'm guessing having to do with the api you are using.

Comment: thanks but I can see "revisions" as an array - any suggestions as to how to get data from it? Thanks.

Comment: If revisions is an array then in PHP you would do ...->revisions[//insert index//]   with the index being either a number like 0 or a key string like 'revision' depeding on how they have the data organized. You can loop through arrays http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php